# Resizing my /home partition

Tags: partitioning, dual-boot, reiserfs

I have 320 GB hard drive which is partitioned as follows:

- / is 16 GB, and is reiserfs
- /home is 300 GB, and is reiserfs
- swap is 4 GB

Now I want to install Windows and have a dual-boot system, but I don't have a free partition. I have more than enough free space on the /home partition, though, and I've heard about tools like `resize_reiserfs`, so my question is, can I shrink that partition to 280 GB and create a new 20 GB partition on which to install Windows, and what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boot from the livecd and use `gparted`.

Comment: IMHO this answer would benefit from being elaborated, e.g. how should the OP use gparted?

Answer (score 0):

gparted is a straightforward GUI tool for editing partitions.

Comment: Could you specify exactly what to do in it? The OP and future visitors may need that info.